# Frequency of numbers in an array

Tags: python, frequency-distribution

I want to get the frequency of numbers in an unsorted array. I am getting the frequency of numbers, but the output shows the frequency of a particular number multiple times. I want the resulting frequency to be shown only once.

```
A = [2,5,1,2,4,6,3,10,3,4,3,2,3,2,15]
B = max(A) + 1
F =[None] * B
for i in range(0,B):
    F[i] = 0 
for j in range(0,len(A)):
    F[A[j]] = F[A[j]] + 1
for k in range(0,len(A)):
    if F[A[k]] != 0:
        print("Frequency of ", A[k] , " is : " , F[A[k]])
```

Output obtained showing frequency of say 2, four times.

```
Frequency of  2  is :  4
Frequency of  5  is :  1
Frequency of  1  is :  1
Frequency of  2  is :  4
Frequency of  4  is :  2
Frequency of  6  is :  1
Frequency of  3  is :  4
Frequency of  10  is :  1
Frequency of  3  is :  4
Frequency of  4  is :  2
Frequency of  3  is :  4
Frequency of  2  is :  4
Frequency of  3  is :  4
Frequency of  2  is :  4
Frequency of  15  is :  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `collections.Counter` for this

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: A = [2,5,1,2,4,6,3,10,3,4,3,2,3,2,15]

In [3]: for k, v in Counter(A).items():
   ...:     print('Frequency of {} is {}'.format(k, v))
   ...:
Frequency of 2 is 4
Frequency of 5 is 1 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` data structure for that. See the well commented code within:

```
# This function creates the collection frequencies
def get_collection_frequency(mylist):
    # Dictionary data structure is used
    mydict = {}
    # Loop through the input list
    for index in mylist:
        # If the item is already there
        if (index in mydict): 
            # Increase its frequency
            mydict[index] += 1
        # If it is not
        else: 
            # Set its frequency equal to 1
            mydict[index] = 1

    # Return the dictionary
    return mydict

A = [2,5,1,2,4,6,3,10,3,4,3,2,3,2,15]

new = get_collection_frequency(A)
print(new)
```

Returns: `{2: 4, 5: 1, 1: 1, 4: 2, 6: 1, 3: 4, 10: 1, 15: 1}`

Answer (score 0):

get the set of the list to remove multiple occurrences, then just loop through:

```
for num in set(A):
    print("Frequency of {} is {}".format(num,A.count(num)))
```

output:

```
Frequency of 1 is 1
Frequency of 2 is 4
Frequency of 3 is 4
Frequency of 4 is 2
Frequency of 5 is 1
Frequency of 6 is 1
Frequency of 10 is 1
Frequency of 15 is 1
```